# Setting the Scope of a Describe block in Rspec to a Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write some concise RSpec tests. The tests are as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Video::Base do
  subject { Video::Base }

  its(:base_uri) { should match(/api\.wistia\.com/) }
  its(:base_uri) { should match(/https/) }

  its(:format) { should == :json }

  describe :default_params do
    its([:api_password]) { should_not be_nil }
  end
end
```

The tests are looking quite nice, but the `describe :default_params` fails. I know that RSpec is capable of calling `its([api_password])`, but the issue is is that the target must be a hash. In this example, you see that I am calling the key onto the `Video::Base` class and not the `#default_params` method. How would I go about setting it to call `its([deafult_params])` onto `Video::Base.default_params` and not onto `Video::Base`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the subject:

```
describe :default_params do
  subject { Video::Base.default_params }

  its([:api_password]) { should_not be_nil }
end
```

Or, to have more flexibility, use `super`:

```
describe :default_params do
  subject { super().default_params }

  its([:api_password]) { should_not be_nil }
end
```

Comment: True, but I was hoping there was a way to dynamically change the scope/target to be onto the method and not have to manually change it via `subject`.